# How to evaluate expression on compilation?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is it possible to somehow tell coffeescript to interpret arithmetic operations, so things like `eleven = 10 + 1` compile to `eleven = 11;`?

[Example on coffescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try:eleven%20%3D%2010%20%2B%201%0Api%20%3D%20Math.PI%0A%0A%0A%23%23%23%0AI%20need%0A%0Avar%20eleven%2C%20pi%3B%0A%0Aeleven%20%3D%2011%3B%0A%0Api%20%3D%203.14...%3B%0A%0A%23%23%23%0A%0A%0A%0A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Coffeescript simply generates javascript.  It does not perform any mathematical preprocessing.